# very long boot up with Ubuntu 10.04.4

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 10.04.3 on Atom. Then I do the update and upgrade with:
 #apt-get update
 #apt-get upgrade
 #apt-get dist-upgrade
The system can boot up now but in almost 2 minutes. After power on and system test, it will stop at "Verifying DMI pool data" for 10 seconds before the GRUB menu comes up. Then after the choosing of one item, to the start up of OS there is 100 seconds of black screen. The start up after that is normal and the operations in the system is also normal.

I am concerned with if it is of hardware problem, or just some problem with the kernel. Also I want to know after "Verifying DMI pool data" what is done? And after we choose an item in GRUB menu, what does the system do? And where can I see the procedure of the whole boot up?

## The /var/log/boot.log is too simple, and this is it:

fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
/dev/mmcblk0p5: clean, ......
/dev/mmcblk0p1: clean, ......
* Starting AppArmor profiles
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox

OK]
* Setting sensors limits

## OK]

Answer (score 1):

That may have been an overkill for your Atom. Check this out for correct [hardware support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks)

and recommended [Ubuntu Netbook Edition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuNetbookEdition)

your best bet would be to use a more current, less demanding version. Such as 11.10

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, blueXrider. I am playing a mini pc, not a netbook. It has a

Comment: I am playing a minipc with Atom Z530, GMA550 graphics card and ath9k wireless.

Comment: I want to figure out if it is hardware problem or kernel problem.